# I need a GREP expression that will find 6 - 10 digits, separated by periods at the 1000 intervals. The periods could be spaces or not at all

Tags: regex

I need a GREP expression that will find 6 - 10 digits, separated by periods at the 1000 intervals. The periods could be spaces or not at all.  It must find:

```
3.878.456.789   
  878.456.789   
   78.456.789   
    8.456.789   
      456.789    
3 878 456 789     
  878 456 789    
   78 456 789    
    8 456 789   
      456 789   
   3878456789     
    878456789    
     78456789    
      8456789   
       456789
```

These numbers could be any digit and aren't bound by those in the example.  The example was given to show the length and pattern for spaces or periods.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code-writing service.

Comment: A simple `grep -P "[\d\. ]+" <file>` would probably suffice, given these broad constraints. Why not provide an example of something it _shouldn't_ catch instead...

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
grep -oP "(?=(?:\D*\d){6,10}\D*$)\b(?:\d{1,3}(?:[ .]\d{3})+|\d+)\b" somepath
```

**Explanation**

- To enforce the 6-10 rule, the lookahead `(?=(?:\D*\d){6,10}\D*)` asserts that what follows is any non-digit then one digit, 6 to ten times, then any number of non-digits until the end of the line
- The digit matcher is surrounded by two word boundaries `\b`
- The digits are `\d{1,3}(?:[ .]\d{3})+` one to three digits followed by one or more instances of (dot or space followed by three digits), OR `|`
- digits `\d+`